# what does it mean by chunksize

Tags: python

```
Data variables:
    time_bnds  (time, bnds) datetime64[ns] dask.array<shape=(14609, 2), chunksize=(364, 2)>
    TMAX_2m    (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<shape=(14609, 34, 17), chunksize=(364, 34, 17)>
    tmax-2m    (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<shape=(14609, 34, 17), chunksize=(14609, 34, 17)>
```

in above description shown in console window, what does it mean by chunksize

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` stores arrays in one big clump.  `dask` chops the array up into smaller pieces, which are called "chunks".